# Setting database class at run time in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have the follow classes for Sqlite and SqlServer:

Class for **SQLite**:

```
Imports System.Data.SQLite
Public Class clsOperDB_SQLite

 Public Shared Function getValue(sql As String) As String

        Try
            Using conn As New SQLiteConnection(strConn_SQLITE)
                Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand()
                    cmd.Connection = conn
                    conn.Open()
                    cmd.CommandText = sql
                    Return cmd.ExecuteScalar
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Return ""

    End Function

End Class
```

Class for **SQLSERVER**:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class clsOperDB_SQLSERVER

            Public Shared Function getValue(sql As String) As String

                Try
                    Using conn As New SqlConnection(strConn_SQLSERVER)
                        Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
                            cmd.Connection = conn
                            conn.Open()
                            cmd.CommandText = sql
                            Return cmd.ExecuteScalar
                        End Using
                    End Using
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try

                Return ""

            End Function

End Class
```

this is my test form:

```
Public Class Form1

    'form level variable
    Dim dbConnector

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim connectionType As String = "SQLITE"

        ' need something like this or any way to set form level variable

        If connectionType = "SQLITE" Then
            dbConnector = clsOperDB_SQLite
        Else
            dbConnector = clsOperDB_SQLSERVER
        End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        'get value from SQLITE
        Dim ValueFromDatabase As String = dbConnector.getValue("select .....")
    End Sub
End Class
```

I need help to define dbConnector variable and set its value, also intellisense should show me class methods, using a parameter I want to change database and avoid using a conditional for every time I want to use one or the other database :

```
   Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim Query As String = "Select ..."
        Dim ValueFromDatabase As String = ""

        ' dont want to use if for each sql query

        If connectionType = "SQLITE" Then
            ValueFromDatabase = clsOperDB_SQLite.getValue(Query)
        Else
            ValueFromDatabase = clsOperDB_SQLSERVER.getValue(Query)
        End If

    End Sub
```

The rest of methods and params for both classes are the same only change class data objects (SQLiteConnection, SqlConnection, and so)

Thanks

Comment: This is not directly related to your question but you might benefit from reading [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/07/database-independent-data-access-layer.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define an interface that species all the common members.  You can then create a class for each data source that implements that interface.  In your application code, you can then declare a variable of that interface type and assign an instance of any class that implements it to that variable.  You can then just use that variable and invoke any member of the interface without caring what type the actual class instance is.

The interface and the implementing classes would look something like this:

```
Public Interface IDataAccessProvider
    Function GetValue(sql As String) As String
End Interface

Public Class SqliteDataAccessProvider
    Implements IDataAccessProvider

    Public Function GetValue(sql As String) As String Implements IDataAccessProvider.GetValue
        'Provide SQLite-specific implementation here.
    End Function

End Class

Public Class SqlServerDataAccessProvider
    Implements IDataAccessProvider

    Public Function GetValue(sql As String) As String Implements IDataAccessProvider.GetValue
        'Provide SQL Server-specific implementation here.
    End Function

End Class
```

Your application code might then look like this:

```
Private dataAccessProvider As IDataAccessProvider

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Read a value that identifies the data source and store it here.
    'The value might be stored in the config file or wherever else is appropriate.
    Dim dataSourceIdentifier As String

    Select Case dataSourceIdentifier
        Case "SQLite"
            dataAccessProvider = New SqliteDataAccessProvider()
        Case "SQL Server"
            dataAccessProvider = New SqlServerDataAccessProvider()
    End Select
End Sub
```

You can then just call `dataAccessProvider.GetValue` in your code without any care for what the data source actually is, except to ensure that your SQL syntax is valid for that data source.

Please note that, while what you do is up to you, I have chosen to use a sane naming convention in this code.  No one would last long working for me using class names like `clsOperDB_SQLSERVER`.  There's a reason you don't see any types with names like that in the .NET Framework.

Comment: works like a charm, also added my other methods, last question: If I only have a method for SQLite, just add a dummy method to SQL Server part?

Comment: You can do that, but I would suggest throwing an `InvalidOperationExcpetion` in that dummy implementation.  That way, you'll be notified if your code accidentally calls a method that it shouldn't be. If you just have an empty method then you might be calling it when you shouldn't and never know, in which case your application might be doing something with the result that it shouldn't.